# Excel mass export to individual PDF "Run time error 1004"

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with 254 entries and I want to export each row as an individual PDF. This code works, I have two spreadsheets. One called dataSheet and one called pdfSheet, It copies the data from dataSheet, pastes it into pdfSheet and then exports pdfSheet as a pdf. The file is then saved into a folder.

However, I get "Run time error 1004" on the 18th time running through (It works perfectly beforhand), every time. I have shuffled the data to make sure thats not a problem but I cant figure out why It would just stop working. I stepped through it in the debugger and on the 18th loop I get the error at:

```
pdfSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="S:\Exports\" & "Export" & "\" & SignName & "\" & "Export.pdf"
```

Here is the full code:

```
Sub ExportPDF()
Dim wholeBook As Workbook
Dim pdfSheet As Worksheet
Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
Dim path As String
Set pdfSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set wholeBook = ThisWorkbook
path = wholeBook.FullName
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 2 To 254
    SignName = dataSheet.Cells(i, 4)
    Category = dataSheet.Cells(i, 3)
    DOB = dataSheet.Cells(i, 5)
    Address = dataSheet.Cells(i, 6)
    Phone = dataSheet.Cells(i, 7)
    Email = dataSheet.Cells(i, 8)
    Instagram = dataSheet.Cells(i, 9)
    Facebook = dataSheet.Cells(i, 10)
    Twitter = dataSheet.Cells(i, 11)
    ECD = dataSheet.Cells(i, 13)
    BOOTP = dataSheet.Cells(i, 14)
    WINRTTP = dataSheet.Cells(i, 15)
    PDOA = dataSheet.Cells(i, 16)
    AGOTP = dataSheet.Cells(i, 17)
    PATISU = dataSheet.Cells(i, 18)
    DACYP = dataSheet.Cells(i, 19)
    PRPFP = dataSheet.Cells(i, 20)
    GGAFTFO = dataSheet.Cells(i, 21)
    AROAFF = dataSheet.Cells(i, 22)
    BS = dataSheet.Cells(i, 23)
    UNISS = dataSheet.Cells(i, 24)
    WPSGA = dataSheet.Cells(i, 25)

    pdfSheet.Cells(3, 1).Value = SignName
    pdfSheet.Cells(5, 1).Value = Category
    pdfSheet.Cells(7, 1).Value = DOB
    pdfSheet.Cells(9, 1).Value = Address
    pdfSheet.Cells(11, 1).Value = Phone
    pdfSheet.Cells(13, 1).Value = Email
    pdfSheet.Cells(15, 1).Value = Instagram
    pdfSheet.Cells(17, 1).Value = Facebook
    pdfSheet.Cells(19, 1).Value = Twitter
    pdfSheet.Cells(21, 1).Value = ECD
    pdfSheet.Cells(23, 1).Value = BOOTP
    pdfSheet.Cells(25, 1).Value = WINRTTP
    pdfSheet.Cells(27, 1).Value = PDOA
    pdfSheet.Cells(29, 1).Value = AGOTP
    pdfSheet.Cells(31, 1).Value = PATISU
    pdfSheet.Cells(33, 1).Value = DACYP
    pdfSheet.Cells(35, 1).Value = PRPFP
    pdfSheet.Cells(37, 1).Value = GGAFTFO
    pdfSheet.Cells(39, 1).Value = AROAFF
    pdfSheet.Cells(41, 1).Value = BS
    pdfSheet.Cells(43, 1).Value = UNISS
    pdfSheet.Cells(44, 1).Value = WPSGA
    If Len(Dir("S:\Exports\" & "Export" & "\" & SignName, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir "S:\Exports\" & "Export" & "\" & SignName
    End If
    pdfSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="S:\Exports\" & "Export" & "\" & SignName & "\" & "Export.pdf"
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.FullName)
    Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The full error is

```
Run-time-error '1004':
Application-defnied or object-defined error
```

Comment: what's the actual error message you receive?

Comment: I edited the question with the error

Comment: What is the value of `SignName` when you get the error? Make sure the value **does not contain** any special character prohibited to name files like / \ * etc.

Comment: get rid of this line `Application.Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.FullName)` It's not needed and will only serve to wack out your process. You can probably get rid of this line too `ThisWorkbook.Save` or move it to the very end. There's no need to save it after every iteration.

Comment: The value of `SignName` is just the persons name and only contains english characters